# MySQL: make a excerpt and copy it to another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to extract text from a MySQL column and copy that text to another column. This text will be an excerpt of the full text in the first column in that I need to trim the 15 leading characters, and then include only the next 140 +/- characters of the text and copy that text to a new column.

This works, of course, to copy all text from one column to another:

`UPDATE`table`SET column1=column2`

And I see the functions [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) to trim text from the left or the right.

*But is it possible to combine LEFT and RIGHT to strip the first 15 characters and then copy the next + or - 140 characters?*

There are no delimiters I can use; all the text will be different. So I need to be able to count characters.

And when I say + or - 140 characters: is it possible to not break a word that may end up at the end of the 140?

**Update 11/27/13**

This query below by Jungsu Heo works and doesn't break words for a table called `wp2_posts`, and the columns `post_excerpt` and `post_content`:

```
UPDATE `wp2_posts`
SET post_excerpt = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110),  1,
IF(LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1)) = 0,
LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)), LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1))));
```

Comment: when you say no delimiters that you can use? not even spaces? how will you able to know if it's end of a word near 140?

Comment: @Tin Tran, thanks, there are spaces in between the words, so finding a space around the location of 140 will work.

Comment: for your updated question with integrating the two queries, see the very bottom of my answer. You can just specify multiple tables in the `UPDATE` and then include your `INNER JOIN` on conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i wonder what happens if i favorite this question, does it show up in my favorites found somewhere on this site? (edit never mind i found the favorite tab) yeh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is interesting. I have tested what you want.

### UPDATED

I have tested. Below query works well even if there is no space. you can test here sqlfiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf19/2/1. (unfortunately, we can't run DML in sqlfiddle)

```
UPDATE tab SET cite = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130),  1, IF(LENGTH(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130)) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130), ' ', -1)) = 0, LENGTH(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130)), LENGTH(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130)) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(col, 16, 130), ' ', -1))));
```

This is step by step example:

```
set @str = 'ABC 1234 56789';

set @ltrim_len = 5;
set @ltrimmed_str = SUBSTRING(@str, @ltrim_len);

set @right_word_warp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@ltrimmed_str, ' ', -1);

set @final_sub_len = LENGTH(@ltrimmed_str) - LENGTH(@right_word_warp);

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ltrimmed_str,  1, IF(@final_sub_len = 0, LENGTH(@ltrimmed_str), @final_sub_len)) AS cite;
+-------+
| cite  |
+-------+
| 1234  |
+-------+
```

### My original Answer (does not work when there is no space)

'ABC 12345 6789' given, then trim 'ABC' and trim '6789' for exact word warp. Finally we get '12345'.

Here is what I tested. step by step example. final answer is last sql.

```
set @str = 'ABC 12345 6789';

SELECT @str;
+----------------+
| @str           |
+----------------+
| ABC 12345 6789 |
+----------------+

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, 5);
+--------------------+
| SUBSTRING(@str, 5) |
+--------------------+
| 12345 6789         |
+--------------------+

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@str, 5), ' ', -1);
+--------------------+
| SUBSTRING(@str, 5) |
+--------------------+
| 12345 6789         |
+--------------------+

SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@str, 5), ' ', -1));
+------------------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@str, 5), ' ', -1)) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    4 |
+------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@str, 5),  1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING(@str, 5)) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@str, 5), ' ', -1)) );
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@str, 5),  1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING(@str, 5)) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@str, 5), ' ', -1)) ) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12345                                                                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Where does the OP put his 140 value?

Comment: I tested your answer on this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf1e9/2/0) it gets rid of my first 2 characters which is good but it always gets rid of the last word as well which i don't think is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @TinTran Hello, I think OP can accomplish with my approach applied. if not, I'll do after work. Thanks.

Comment: @Jungsu Heo, Thanks, this works great. It doesn't break words, either. I have one more question: I need to select the WordPress category that I need to run this query on so it only produces excerpts for posts in that category. I don't know how to integrate the query that selects the category with your query. I've edited my question above.

Comment: what do you know turns out my answer was so wrong at word boundaries :( I have updated my answer and added more test cases

Comment: @songdogtech Sorry. (as you know) I'm not good at English and have never used WP ever before. Honestly, I could not understand your second question. (seems like looking for LEFT JOIN, but not sure). If second question is not related 1st question. why don't you post new question about it? sorry couldn't help you much more.

Comment: @Jungsu Heo: Thanks! I should open a new question on integrating the queries.

Answer (score 1):

here's an example [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be6ef/1/0)

Just replace the number 2 with your 15 leading characters, and the number 10 with 140 and it should work. it drops the first 2 characters, then find 10 characters and drop the last chunk by locating a space at the end.

```
 UPDATE `table` SET column1=
                     LEFT(                   LEFT(RIGHT(column2,LENGTH(column2)-2),10),
                          10-
                          LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(RIGHT(column2,LENGTH(column2)-2),10)),1)
                         );
```

Alternately you can use `SUBSTRING` instead of `RIGHT` like in this [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c87f61/1/0) just replace occurences of 3 with 16(your 15+1) and replace occurences of 10 with 140

```
UPDATE `table` SET column1=
 LEFT(                   LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),10),
      10-
      LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),10)),1)
     );
```

edit: actually, since you want a word to end at 140 you might have to replace occurences of 10 with 141 instead since it drops the last chunk of word it finds so if your word ends at 140 you don't want it to drop so try 141.
-------------------------------------------
**UPDATED**
The above answers are wrong it doesn't work for other cases. **NEW ANSWER BELOW**
this answer has more cases to test around the 15(your 140) boundary
here's the [sqlFiddle proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b622/1/0)
and here's the code:

```
UPDATE `table` SET column1=
 IF(LENGTH(LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),16)) < 16,
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),16),
    LEFT(LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),16),
         LENGTH(LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),16))-
         LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(column2,3),16)),1)
        )
   );
```

Just change all occurences of 3 to 16(your 15+1) and occurences of 16 to 141(your 140+1).
-------------------------------------------------------------
answer for latest UPDATED QUESTION

```
UPDATE wp2_posts,
       wp2_term_relationships,
       wp2_term_taxonomy
SET post_excerpt = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110),  1,
IF(LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1)) = 0,
LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)), LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1))));
WHERE (wp2_posts.ID = wp2_term_relationships.object_id)
AND (wp2_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp2_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
     AND wp2_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
     AND wp2_term_taxonomy.term_id = '213');
```

or if you prefer to keep all your `INNER JOIN` syntax
 like below

```
UPDATE wp2_posts
  INNER JOIN wp2_term_relationships
  ON (wp2_posts.ID = wp2_term_relationships.object_id)
  INNER JOIN wp2_term_taxonomy
  ON (wp2_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp2_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  AND wp2_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
  AND wp2_term_taxonomy.term_id = '213')
SET post_excerpt = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110),  1,
  IF(LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1)) = 0,
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)), LENGTH(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110)) -
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, 55, 110), ' ', -1))));
```

Comment: yeah i am pretty sure you have to use 141 to replace occurences of 10 i just tested with a string of 15 and i had to use 16 so it wouldn't drop my word ending at 15 characters.

Comment: Thanks! But neither example with the category selection works, but I will open a new question, as that's the best thing for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the usage of LEFT, RIGHT and SUBSTRING operators within mySQL? You can easily grab characters 16 through whatever.

`UPDATE _table_ SET column1 = SUBSTRING(column2,16)`

As for breaking words, You may have to use PHP for that.